# Unninstalling Julia from Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: linux, julia

I already tried `rm -rf ~/.julia` and even `sudo apt-get remove julia`, and still, whenever I type on Linux terminal `julia` the programming language "opens".
I had 3 versions of Julia (had problems in installing too), they were 1.0.4, 1.5.2 and 0.4, right now there is only 1.0.4 left. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Try this:        sudo apt purge julia

Comment: It says, `Package 'julia' is not installed, so not removed`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with `type -p julia` to see which path the remaining `julia` has.

If it is a known remaining package then

```
dpkg -S $(type -p julia)
```

will tell you the package name, and you can remove the package the usual way.

If it is *not* a package but something you installed directly from GitHub or julia.org then you may just have to `rm -rf` it (very carefully).